# AWS Kinesis Firehose Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a doubt I have been unable to solve by reading the documentation.

I know the price is decided by GB ingested and each PUT operation is rounded to the nearest 5 KB. We are designing a solution that will have very small events, and we don't know if we could reduce costs by using the PutRecordsBatch method, that would allow us to send up to 500 events in one call and be closer to that 5 KB so that billing does not explode.

In summary, it's not clear for me what a PUT operation is (put into the stream, put into the destination...)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, batching does not affect the pricing of firehose. Please see this section of the FAQ:

https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/faqs/?nc=sn&loc=5#Pricing_and_billing

We are facing the same issue and have already tried batching. We are searching for a way around this billing issue.